# Hibernate/JPA: ManyToMany and OneToMany relationship on same attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem on combining a ManyToMany with an OneToMany relationship.

I have entries and categories. Every entry has one main category and 0..* subcategories.

This is my implementation:

```
public class Entry extends AbstractEntity {
    [...]

    private Category mainCategory;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = hello.Category.class)
    private Set<Category> subCategories;

    [...]
}

public class Category extends AbstractEntity {
    [...]

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = hello.Entry.class, mappedBy = "subCategories")
    private Set<Entry> entries;

    [...]
}
```

The ManyToMany relationship is functional but i don't know how to implement the OneToMany relationship.

Comment: Have you tried @ManyToOne on mainCategory?

Comment: I tried `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainCategory")` on `private Set<Entry> entries` and `@ManyToOne` on `private Category mainCategory` but i got "`@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` on the same property is not allowed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define two separate mapping on a single attribute. The data it should contain is not well-defined. Should it contain the Entries mapped by the `subCategories` field or by the `mainCategory` or both? Since there is not a singe sensible answer for all use cases, JPA disallows such multiple annotations.

You can however just add a field corresponding to the inverse (non-owning) side of the one-to-many relationship.

Define it like this:

```
public class Category ...

  @ManyToOne(mappedBy="mainCategory")
  private Set<Entry> entriesHavingThisCategoryAsMain;
```

I could not come up with a better name for the inverse side, so use your context :)

EDIT: you do not need to define the `targetEntity` attribute for typed Collections except you have multiple `Category` and `Entry` entities in different packages.